# Rails 5 - Updating model with Ajax and appending request response html into view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am making a call to User controller update action via form with remote: true. I want to render updated user html in view, so I have this code in controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      format.html {
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_back fallback_location: @user
      }
      format.js { render partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user } }
    else
      format.html { render 'show' }
      format.js {}
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine, server responds with correct rendered html and status 200. The problem is with my coffescript:

```
$ ->
  $(".edit_user[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log(e)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(status)
    console.log(xhr)
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut()
    if $(this).data('action') == 'hire'
      $('#active-users').append data
    else
      $('#archive-users').append data
```

This code does not execute and I have no idea why. I found that if I remove `render partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user }` from controller coffescript executes (but of course I need this rendered html).

How can I fix my coffescript to execute properly? I'm pretty new to JS and CoffeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use '`remote: true`', that will automatically execute the Javascript file of the corresponding controller action, so in this case users 'update'. There is no need to have a separate file binding ajax:success or anything like that.

So, first change:

```
format.js { render partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user } }
```

To:

```
format.js {}
```

Then create a file views/user/update.js.erb, and inside that file add this:

```
$('#active-users').append('<%= j render partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user } %>')
```

The 'j' will escape the output of the HTML so the Javascript will not throw an error. Once the controller action completes, it will append the contents of the partial to #active-users. You can of course add any additional Javascript you need to this file as well.